# Stop Saving Guid.Empty during controller testing in asp.net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I am currently testing the controller of my asp.net web api project. I am using moq and nunit for testing purpose. To test fail cases, i am not passing the one of the Guid parameter of the model. Inside the controller, the left one Guid become Guid.Empty and is saved. This is not what testing hopes to get. How can I handle this problem.

My Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Guid ModelId {get;set;}
    public Guid NunitId {get;set;}
}
```

Inside test method...

```
MyModel m = new MyModel();
//here I am not sending ModelId 
m.NunitId  = model.NunitId;

var result = _controller.Create(m);
```

Inside controller...

```
MyModel m = new MyModel();
m.ModelId = model.ModelId;
//here ModelId value becomes Guid.Empty i.e.{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
m.NunitId  = model.NunitId;

_repoWrapper.TableName.Create(m);
_repoWrapper.TableName.SaveChanges(anyparams);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? You're seeing default values which is as expected.

Comment: Yes that is expected default value. But I dont want to save that to database. Rather want to throw some error or something else.